# Get the first line of the final sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so

[image]

I want to get the first date (column "dt") of the final "id" sequence.

According to this example  the final "id" sequence is 6
I Want to get the date of the first appearance  **"2015-01-04"**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: How do you determine this *sequence*? The rows with the latest dates sharing the same `id` value?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. The 6 contains three different dates, the earliest is 2013-01-26. A table has no inherent order, so either you use id or dt for the ordering. Since id is not unique you have to use another column to avoid an arbitrary order. So 2013-01-26 would be the correct result. **But** i assume that you've omitted the primary key column. Maybe you can use it instead.

Comment: @elish: too many different answers for your question. I suppose that we wil find out what you really want only after you accept one of the questions.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The table is ordered by dt, so the last "sequence" is "6,6" (row 5 & 6) and the first date of this sequence is 2015-01-04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach utilizes two ROW_NUMBERs, both will increment similar for the first *n* rows with the same `id`:

```
SELECT MIN(id), MIN(dt)
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      tab.*,
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn,
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn2
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
WHERE RN = RN2
```

Comment: Isn't it the same aproach that gordon has shown already? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34655352/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yep, he posted his answer while I was writing mine.

Comment: @elish: Simply look at the result of the Derived Table, as long as the `id` is the same both calculations return the same number, when the `id` changes the numbers start differing...

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a pain.  One method using standard SQL:

```
select min(t.date)
from t cross join
     (select top 1 id
      from t
      order by date desc
     ) tt
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.date >= t.date and t2.id <> tt.id
                 );
```

Another method uses `row_number()` and an observation:  if we enumerate the rows by date in descending order and we enumerate the rows by date in descending order and partitioned by `id`, then the values are the same for the last sequence of ids.  We can use this as a condition to get the minimum date:

```
select min(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date desc) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum_id
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = seqnum_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 dt FROM 'your Table' WHERE id = 6 ORDER BY dt ASC
```

Or if you don't know that 6 is max

```
SELECT TOP 1 dt FROM 'your Table' ORDER BY id DESC, dt ASC
```

Comment: Maybe but not giving the desired result which is `2015-01-04` instead of `2013-01-26`.

Comment: Yeah, i dont't saw that there was another id with 6. (2013-01-26)  Just think about what could be done.

Comment: The last id dont have to be the max Value.

Comment: Okay, now understanding.

Comment: Hmmmm, i think with your possibilities you can't reach your Goal, like Tim Schmelter say in the comment.

Comment: @elish: the point is that a table has no inherent order like the result view you've shown above. What was the query that returned this result? If you haven't used an `ORDER BY` the order is arbitrary and unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

Since a table has no inherent order the order of your "sequence" isn't clear. If you use id + dt the correct result would be `2013-01-26` instead of `2015-01-04` since it has also id=6 but is earlier. I assume that you've actually omitted the column you've used for the ordering, probably the primary-key or another date-column.

So presuming that there's a PK `PK_ID`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dt
FROM dbo.TableName t1
WHERE id = (SELECT TOP 1 id 
            FROM dbo.TableName 
            ORDER BY PK_ID DESC)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
    WHERE t2.PK_ID > t1.PK_ID
      AND t2.id   <> t1.id
)
ORDER BY dt ASC
```

This query determines the id of the last record(acc. the PK) in a subquery(the optimizer will do this only once) and then filters the records by this id. This will return three records with id=6. The `NOT EXISTS` correlated subquery will ensure that there is no other record later(acc. the primary-id) with a different id. This will filter out the third record which would otherwise have the earliest date. 
The remaining two last records are ordered by dt and `TOP 1` returns only the ealiest one `2015-01-04`.

Comment: There *is* an order, the result is ordered by `dt`, it's just hard to notice :)

Comment: @dnoeth: yes, now i've also noticed it. But without mentioning it explicitly OP could also have used a different column or none at all. If it's `dt` OP would have to replace `PK_ID` with `dt` in my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the following query

```
SELECT TOP 1 dt
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC, dt ASC
```

Comment: Doesn't guarantee first date for the id is returned.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the first date (column "dt") of the final "id" sequence.

I suppose that means: find minimum dt ("first date") for maximum id ("final id"):

```
SELECT MIN(DT) FROM THE_TABLE
    WHERE
        id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM THE_TABLE)
```